# Data Validation and Scanners in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, validation

I have a question regarding data validation and scanners.The following piece of code checks userinput.Anything other than an integer is not allowed and the user is asked to re-enter a value.My question is that the code works only if the scanner is declared within the while loop.The program executes infinitely if the scanner is declared outside.Why is that?Thanks.

```
int UserInp;
    boolean dataType=false;
    while(dataType==false)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {

    System.out.print("\nEnter a number: ");
    UserInp=sc.nextInt();

    dataType=true;
        }
        catch(Exception JavaInputMismatch)
        {

            System.out.println("Option not available.Try again.");

        }

    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. I got it working fine. Are you sure the only change you're making is moving `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` to before the loop?

Comment: I _was_ able to reproduce his problem, and I'm investigating it now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How'd you get it to behave like that?

Comment: I'm running his code as a console app from IntelliJ.  I'm sure this is some sort of artifact...just trying to find out what exactly.

Comment: Oh, actually, I replicated it too. It only happens on invalid input, heh.

Comment: On a side note, although `while(dataType==false)` is technically correct syntax, it is considered more elegant to express it as `while(!dataType)`. Also, you could use a `do-while` loop for cases where you want to force at least one iteration.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.I'm just a beginner so I'm pretty bad when it comes to knowing correct programming practices.

Comment: I think sometimes it's fine to use `== false`. It's much more clear, and if you name your variables well (like instead of dataType, if it were intEntered), it would read like real English.

Comment: @Purag as I stated before, it is technically correct syntax. However, the global programming community prefer not to be redundant by evaluating a boolean using the `==` operator.

Comment: I think I'm accustomed to seeing it as a tutor for an intro Java class. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem!

What happens is that the Scanner attempts to translate the non-integer to an integer, and realizes it can't -- so it throws an InputMismatchException. However, it only advances past the token if the translation was successful.

Meaning, the invalid string is still in the input buffer, and it will fail the translation every single time you loop and try to call `nextInt()`. You never set `dataType` to true, and so you loop infinitely.

To see this in action, you can grab the arbitrary content in your catch block and print it out:

```
catch(Exception JavaInputMismatch){
    System.out.println( sc.next() );
    System.out.println("Option not available.Try again.");
}
```

Indeed, after invalid input, we get the following:

```
Enter a number: hello
hello
Option not available.Try again.

Enter a number:
```

And we don't loop infinitely. This is because the call to `next()` grabbed the value from the input buffer and advanced the scanner's pointer into that buffer to the next slot, which is now empty. So `nextInt()` will wait for input in that case.

Oh, and the reason it works fine if you initialize in the loop is that the scanner will always start reading input fresh; scanners don't share state across instances, so the "hello" that was in the buffer for the previous iteration isn't in the buffer for the next one due to the reinitialization.

*Technically*, it's still in the standard input buffer, but the scanner's pointer into that buffer is beyond the invalid string because it will start reading any *new* input, not existing input.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Purag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814761/purag)'s answer, you could alternatively use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to advance the Scanner past the current line.

So your catch block will look like this:

```
catch(Exception JavaInputMismatch)
    {
        System.out.println("Option not available.Try again.");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question.

You may get it!

The answer is simple. The `Scanner object` is kept live till the end of the execution as it is declared outside the `while loop`. Look this problem in the memory level.

The Scanner object is kept live so while entering the loop next time still the value(String value) will be there in Scanner object and it doesn't listens keyboard as the exception is already thrown.So the loop keeps going.

Note : The `next()` method in `Scanner` class will accept all the types of keyboard input but not the rest of the methods such as `nextInt(), nextFloat()` etc..,