# Check that scanner input IS ONLY an integer

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a simple program to validate that a user's input is a positive integer. However I am running into an issue when I use the Scanner.hasNextInt() method. If input contains an integer such as "five 6" my program will read the 6 in as an integer. However, I want such a statement to be invalid and prompt the user to need to enter ONLY an integer value. And therefore the program would output "Please enter an integer value: ".

This is what my program looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputValidation {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // INPUT VALIDATION FOR INTEGERS AND POSITIVE NUMBERS
        int input = 0;
        boolean validationSuccessful = false;

        System.out.print("Please enter the input: ");
        do {

            // validate that the input is an integer
            if (in.hasNextInt() == true) {
                input = in.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter an integer value: ");
                in.next();
                continue;
            }

            // validate that the input is positive
            if (input < 0) {
                System.out.print("Please print a POSITIVE integer: ");
                continue;
            } else {
                validationSuccessful = true;
            }
            System.out.println("The input is: " + input);
        } while (validationSuccessful == false);

    }
}
```

Edit:
I understand the difference between next() vs. nextLine(). However, my issue is the validation aspect of the line actually only being an integer vs. the line containing an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Validation and Scanners in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770426/data-validation-and-scanners-in-java)

Comment: Do you mean you want to use nextLine() to discard the whole line instead of next() which discards a word?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, I would want it to discard the entire line if it is not only an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discard a line use

```
in.nextLine();
```

if you use

```
in.next();
```

it only reads one word/token. (By "word" I mean anything between whitespace)

> I only want to accept an integer value as the input, not just if the line contains an integer.

```
int value;
while(true) {
    // a number please.
    try {
         value = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
         if (value > 0)
              break;
         // not positive. 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         // not an integer
    }
}
```

Note: 0 is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: My problem is that I'm not sure how to implement that the the line is equal to just an integer. Basically I want to check within my if condition that the input is the integer. Is it possible to have something like that the line is an integer as opposed to the line contains an integer? I only want to accept an integer value as the input, not just if the line contains an integer.

Comment: You can read the line with `in.nextLine()` and attempt to parse it with `Integer.parseInt(line)`

Comment: I know it's just an example but I would add a print to request input between `while` and `try`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int input = 0;
    boolean intExist = false; //changes
    boolean validationSuccessful = false;

    System.out.print("Please enter the input: ");
    do {

        // validate that the input is an integer
        if (in.hasNextInt() == true) {
            input = in.nextInt(); 
            intExist = true;  //changes
        } else {
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value: ");
            in.next();
            continue;
        }

        // validate that the input is positive
     if(intExist){    //changes
        if (input < 0) {
            System.out.print("Please print a POSITIVE integer: ");
            continue;
        } else {
            validationSuccessful = true;
        }
        System.out.println("The input is: " + input);
    }
} while (validationSuccessful == true);   // changes
```

Wherever it is written "//changes " , I made a changes to your code.
As per my understanding you want that if input contains any things except int value , it should show " Please enter a integer value ".
If any tokens inside the input contains non-integer values , the loops will get break and it will also print a message " Please enter a integer value "..